# D3js draw over time?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timer, timeline

I'm trying to draw earthquakes over a period of few months on a map. With the following code I've drawn all the earthquake occurences but I want to scale the time period and make it video-like.

```
svg.selectAll(".shock")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("circle")
 .attr("class", 'shock')
 .attr("r", 5)
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([
        d.lng,
        d.lat
    ]) + ")";
 });
```

How do I show all these earthquakes in a 15 second animation?
One way I've thought is: append all circles (date-sorted)  with `radius 0`, then increase the radius of the first one, and `setTimeout` to increase the radius of the next one and so on.. Is there any better way?

I know about time scales, but don't know how to use them to draw over time?

Comment: Asking Google yields some nice examples covering what you are trying to achieve. I think [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/6832422) is doing exactly what you are after. It uses `setInterval()` to trigger the addition of new circles, which are appended one after another when they need to be drawn. Although not exactly fitting your needs, another [nice example](http://bl.ocks.org/tnightingale/4718717) featuring a selection using `d3.svg.brush()` may provide interesting insights.

Comment: Yet [another visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/benelsen/4969007). This one is not working because data could not be read, but analyzing the code should convey the basic ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First scale your min and max time (using `.getTime()`) over the animation duration

```
var timeScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([min, max])
                    // a one second delay before we start + 14 seconds of earthquakes
                    .range([1000, 15000])
```

Then just set timeouts to display the points according to the scaled time

```
...
.attr("display", function (d) {
    // set a timeout to show this at the right time
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        d3.select(self).attr("display", "block")
    }, timeScale((new Date(d.When)).getTime()));

    return "none";
})
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4c1ukb1z/ - you'll need to update the projections and the When attribute parsing according to your code / data structure.

---

Of course, it would be possible to do this using timescales too if you are getting date time objects.